# Is it possible to modify the default "index of" page generated by a browser for a directory without an index file (html/php)?

Tags: php, html

I have a directory on a website that has no index.html or otherwise default home page. When I navigate to the site, the browser generates the default "index of /...." list of the files in the directory.

I want to keep the simple setup (i.e. no new homepage for the directory, just the default "index of/..." list generated by the browser), but I want to have an option to **upload** files to the directory (if possible?).

Perhaps an additional link next to the "Name, Last modified, Size, Description" links called "Upload" that can be used to upload a file to the directory.

Thanks! (Also, sorry if this is impossible/strange/etc)

Comment: The software that you are using to host your PHP/html is controlling this behavior. Please tell us what you're using, such as apache, httpd, etc.

Comment: As for uploading a file through the browser, you will have to create an HTML page with a form yourself, and write the code to receive it server-side. Searching for "HTTP file upload" should give you pointers.

Comment: Only browser-only way I know of is to download the discontinued Mozilla 1.7 browser which can upload if you load the site as ftp://<userid:password@>www.yoursite.com

Comment: @mplungjan's suggestion means using the FTP protocol, which is completely different from HTTP, and requires having a different FTP server application installed and configured server-side

Comment: @DaveChen: It's an apache server.

Comment: @personne3000: Thanks, I was just wondering if it were possible to do it without a separate html page, or if in general its possible to modify but not replace the default view of the "index of" page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that in a manner that's worth it.

The best solution might be doing that index.php file and making it to mimic the default "Index of.." + your wanted functionalities.

Would this be good for a solution?

Also you could use [this](http://phpfm.sourceforge.net/) (or other PHP file manager) and leave only the upload and directory tree + files list on.

Edit:

Found [this](http://perishablepress.com/better-default-directory-views-with-htaccess/) and it looks like it's exactly what you were looking for. You can add custom content to the default "Index of..." view.

Comment: Thanks, that might be the easiest option. I understand theres plenty of good file managers, i was just wondering if a simple elegant way were possible with minimum mods

Comment: Maybe you could load that default view in the header of your file upload script. I'm not sure if that's possible or how to do it. Maybe someone knows.

Comment: Very pretty. Could you include a tiny bit of code? Just in case of link rot?

Comment: You're welcome, Kurt! 
@mplungjan That article can't be split into small pieces and still be understandable. But don't worry, the link is up since 2008 and I'm sure it will remain like this; it's a good site.